In Django with DjangoCMS how do I reverse an URL when using the sites framework (the URL is on a different site)?
I have a Django install with DjangoCMS and ~20 sites (with Djangos sites framework).
I would like to create a link from one site (https://a.example.com/) to another site (https://b.example.com/).
For example I have an CMSApp called persons and a single URL for example https://a.example.com/en/person/aaa/ and https://b.example.com/de/team/aaa/.
If I try to reverse it like this on a.example.com:
reverse("persons:canonic-person", kwargs={"person_slug": self.slug})

I get: /en/person/aaa/
But I want to be able to switch to b.example.com and get /de/team/aaa/ or even better: https://b.example.com/de/team/aaa/.
How do I achieve that?

You put the hostname in front.

@willeM_VanOnsem I don't understand.

f"https://b.example.com{reverse("persons:canonic-person", kwargs={"person_slug": self.slug})}"

@willeM_VanOnsem That won't help, resp. is just the very minor point. Note that the slug is different on both sites. If I would do it that way I would get https://b.example.com/en/person/aaa/ but I need https://b.example.com/de/team/aaa/. The domain-part is almost trivial, but the slug-part is what the real question is.

django-cms has the page_url tag to get URLs for a CMS page. You can pass that a site object. Something along this line might help you, depending on the database setup between sites.
https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/templatetags.html#page-url
